# How can I parse CSV data with internal commas in data using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

The data I need to parse looks like:

```
[fild1, filed2, .... filedn] , [filed1, filed2, .... filedn] .....
```

I call it a special form of [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) data because there are two kinds of comma:

1. those commas outside the [] pair are
   served as the separator between
   different records.
2. those commas inside  the [] pair are
   served as the separator between
   different fields.

So in this case using `split(',' , $data)` will not serve my needs which is to parse the data and get every record in the data.

Comment: Who said anything about Python?

Comment: @carillonator, It's just standard Python vs Perl flame-baiting.  Ignore it or flag it.  Sadly, it's fairly typical on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
my @out = map{[split/,/]} $data =~ /\[([^\]]+)\]/g;
```

example:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$data='[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]';
@a=map{[split/,/]} $data =~ /\[([^\]]+)\]/g;
print Dumper @a;
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1',
          '2',
          '3'
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          '4',
          '5'
        ];
$VAR3 = [
          '6'
        ];
```

Answer (score 2):

How about: `my @parts = split(/\]/, $data);`, and then you can iterate over `@parts`, remove the heading `[` and split once more by ","

You can also make the initial split like so:
 `my @parts = split(/\] , /, $data);` and that will save you some more cleanup later. Just be sure to only use this method if your data's whitespaces are consistent.

Comment: That's a bad regex for the split, since split's first argument is always interpreted as a regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
my @a = split /\]\s*,\s*\[/, $data;
```

and get rid of first '[' and last ']'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example that assumes that the value in `$data` is valid.

```
my @data = map { [ split ',', $_ ] } $data =~ / \[ ([^\[\]]*) \] ,? /xg;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try out Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS. go to CPAN to download.